# ForeignKey Relation vs. Duplicate data

Tags: database, performance, foreign-keys

I have Comments table as follows

```
Comments
----------------
Id
ContentId
CreateDate
UserId
Text
ImageUrl
```

When I want to get comments, I use following sql query:

```
SELECT Comments.*, Users.Name AS Username, Users.Thumbnail AS UserThumbnail 
FROM Comments, Users 
WHERE Users.ID = Comments.UserId
```

Can it increase the performance if I add Username and UserThumbnail columns into Comments table and just use `SELECT * FROM Comments` query

```
Comments
-----------
Id
ContentId
CreatedDate
UserId
Username
UserThumbnail
Text
ImageUrl
```

Comment: Select * is a SQL anti pattern too. Do not ever use it in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query should be fast already if you have properly indexed. No you should not consider denormalizing as then you will have to add triggers to keep the data up-to-date as it changes which will slow down inserts. Or you will have bad data in your database which makes the whole thing worthless.

BTW, implicit joins area a sql antipattern and you should stop using them. It is easy to get an accidental crioss join, you can get incorrect results if you combine them with a left join later and they are haredr to maintain and were replaced more than 20 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes it may well improve the performance of the query, but at the expense of redundancy - you will now have to store the Username and Thumbnail multiple times.

This is the basic tenet of relational database design - eliminating duplicates by using joins via foreign keys.